# How do you keep records consistent across subforms in Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, subform

I have a form broken up into multiple different subforms, which I'd like to switch freely among without changing the record I'm looking at. More specifically, I select which record I want to modify on a "basic information" tab and then when I switch to other tabs--like my "costs" tab--I'd like for the same record to be selected. How do I do that in Access 2010? How do I do that with pop-up menus? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common approach in Access (and in fact in most software) is to use a tab control.

So you build the top part of the form with the one main record, and then for the seveal child forms, you simply drop in a tab control. Here is a Access screen shot:

[image]

And here is another Access screen shot:

[image]

And when I click on the other tab, you see this:

[image]

So the sub form that you display on the tab control can be fixed form, or even a continues form – it really is your choice.

It really is a very basic and common setup. As noted, the nice part is such a UI does not require any code on your part. As noted, you are free to place controls behind each tab you add, but you also free to place sub forms behind each tab also to display that child informaton. The "main" part of the form will not change and can continue to display the "main" reocrd information.

Note that we talking about using a tab contorl. Like this one:

[image]

Comment: Right. I have that tab control, but the problem is that the record changes back to the first one when I switch sub tabs: http://i.imgur.com/jTxFf.png . In that example, I can select the record using the "consortium name" combo box, but when I change to say, "costs," it automatically just goes with the first record.

Comment: I don't see ANY tab control on your example form. There is a MASSIVE AND HUGE AND LARGE AND HUMONGOUS AND  COLOSSAL AND GIGANTIC difference between a tab control on form as oppose to a navigation form. We are talking about using a tab control here. I pasted in a new picture above, and note the circle I shown. So NEVER talking about using a navigation form, and that is a Mount Everest difference of a suggestion. See the above new picture + edit I added here.

Comment: So you're right. While I think Access 2010 has the ability to support what I set out to do, I can't seem to get it to cooperate. I'll convert everything to tabs, then! Thanks for the pointer. Thus ends my Recalcitrant Subforms Saga.